# Expiring key on connection close

Tags: redis

I was trying to get distributed lock using redis.  After googling I found one solution 
https://github.com/jeffomatic/redis-exp-lock-js/blob/master/js/lib/redis_lua.js

But problem with this solution is: 
If application crashed. There is no way to recover the lock before timeout. What I want is , to automatically expire key on connection close. 
Is there any command/ expire setting in redis? For expiring the key on connection close.

Answer (score 0):

No, redis does not do that for you (you can only do this on the client side)

What you can do to alleviate this deadlock problem is to store the timestamp of last acquisition and use that to determine if a lock is still valid or if its a deadlock.

Clients acquiring the lock will ignore it if the value stored in it is set too long ago (eg. current_time - lock_time > timeout).

Note: This requires clients' clock to be syncd.

EDIT:

If LUA is an option for you then you dont need the clients to have syncd clocks